# Java generics <?> and how to deal with it in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have an API (from third party java library) that looks like:

```
    public List<?> getByXPath(String xpathExpr)
```

defined on a class called DomNode

I try this in scala function:

```
1: def removeChild(node: DomNode, xpath: String) {
2:               val lst: List[?] =  node.getByXPath(xpath)
3:      val child: DomNode = lst(0)
4:                child.getParentNode().removeChild(child)
    }
```

but it does not compile in scala. I get error in line 2.

As per the answers I modified it and now it is:

```
1: def removeChild(node: DomNode, xpath: String) {
2:            val lst = node.getByXPath(xpath)
3:            val child = lst(0).asInstanceOf[DomNode]            
4:            child.getParentNode().removeChild(child)
    }
```

Now I get error on line 3: lst of type java.util.List[?0] does not take parameters

I also tried `val lst: List[_] =  node.getByXPath(xpath)`  but this gives me error right on this same line:

```
type mismatch;
 found : java.util.List[?0] where type ?0
 required: scala.List[_]
```

So I am still stuck.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: I get the impression that you're asking one question per line you write. There are 5 questions from the last two days, all related to `Java <?>` somehow. Did you read some book or tutorial first, or is SE your only tool, like an enhanced compiler with personal error messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re your error on line 3: remember that it is a Java list, not a Scala list, so try

```
val child = lst.get(0).asInstanceOf[DomNode]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's wrong with your code:

```
def removeChild(node: DomNode, xpath: String) {
     val lst: List[?] =  node.getByXPath(xpath)
           /* ^^^^^^^ This probably refers to scala.collection.immutable.List,
                      which is a totally different type from the 
                      java.util.List that getByXPath returns.*/
          /* Also, the ? needs to be changed into an _ in Scala */


     val child: DomNode = lst(0)
           /* Two problems here: First, java.util.List won't support indexing 
              with parentheses. Second, you need to typecast the result to get a
              DomNode. */


     child.getParentNode().removeChild(child)
}
```

Here's a corrected version:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
def removeChild(node:DomNode, xpath:String) {
   val lst:scala.collection.Seq[_] = node.getByXPath(xpath)
       /* triggers an implicit conversion that wraps the Java List in a Scala Seq */

   val child: DomNode = lst(0).asInstanceOf[DomNode]
   child.getParentNode().removeChild(child)
}
```

(Leaving out the type annotation will still work -- instead of causing the conversion when you assign `val lst`, it will cause the conversion when you try to call `lst(0)`.)

Another corrected version that doesn't convert to a Scala `Seq`:

```
def removeChild(node:DomNode, xpath:String) {
   val lst:java.util.List[_] = node.getByXPath(xpath)
       /* you can remove the type annotation here, but I left it in
          for pedagogical purposes */

   val child: DomNode = lst.get(0).asInstanceOf[DomNode]
   child.getParentNode().removeChild(child)
}
```

Comment: Please, change `?` into `_`, and also remark on the fact that it needs changing. Your answer is one of the best ones, imho, except that you missed that.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
val lst: java.util.List[_] =  node.getByXPath(xpath)
```

Comment: Kim's right. @amc, you should avoid modifying your question is a way such that answers that made sense before your edit become irrelevant all of a sudden. Other people may also be interested in the solution to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
val arr = DomNode.getByXPath("foo").toArray
val child = lst(0).asInstanceOf[DomNode]
```

Apparently there is no implicit conversion for wildcarded Java lists to Scala lists, therefor, the `val lst` you were creating was of the type `java.util.list` which of course does not have an apply method. I worked around this by just creating a Scala array from the list.

Comment: Umm, that only works if you `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._`

Comment: Not for me, worked just fine without importing anything at all (not in REPL). Tested with Scala 2.9

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```
def removeChild(node: DomNode, xpath: String) {
    // Let type inference do the work for you
    // val lst: List[?] =  node.getByXPath(xpath)
    val lst = node.getByXPath(xpath)

    // Also, do not confuse Java's and Scala's collections
    // val child: DomNode = lst(0)
    val child = lst.get(0)

    // Finally, since you do not have a static guarantee of the type,
    // match on it
    //     child.getParentNode().removeChild(child)
    child match {
        case domNode: DomNode => domNode.getParentNode().removeChild(domNode)
        case _ =>
    }
}
```